# Duplicate files copied in APK lib/x86/librealm-jni.so - Conflict with cache in ~/.gradle/cache

Tags: android, jar, java-native-interface, realm, react-native

The app builds successfully but while running, i get the following error:

```
Duplicate files copied in APK lib/x86/librealm-jni.so
File1: /Users/apple/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.realm/realm-android/0.87.1/6d9a1bba4e31252cc8183aa27a32e6edbdacaeb7/realm-android-0.87.1.jar
File2: /Users/apple/NodeProjects/react-native-mod/droid/databinder/build/intermediates/bundles/default/jni
```

When I remove the realm dependency from databinder module, it cannot find the lib.

How do I remove the cached version of jar file from adding into the APK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below into your `gradle.build` file

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'lib/x86/librealm-jni.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/librealm-jni.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi/librealm-jni.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/librealm-jni.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/librealm-jni.so'
}
```

This option will only pick up the **.so** files when it is firstly seen by the build system and ignore all the subsequent same **.so** files.